Blazor : access components in the MainLayout in the page
I am working on a Blazor Webassembly application on .net 6 and has a structure of page as follows.
There is a MainLayout.razor page where is a header bar which renders few small razor components using "DyamicComponent"
and in the @Body part the actual page (e.g. abc.razor) loads.
<div class="top-row px-4"
    @foreach (var item in BaseParameters)
    {
        if (HasParametersProperty(item))
        {
            <DynamicComponent Type="@item" Parameters="parameters" />
        }
        else
        {
            <DynamicComponent Type="@item" />
        }
    }

</div>
<div id="mainContent" class="content px-4" style="padding:0;">
            @Body
        </div>
    
    @code
    {
        public List<Type> BaseParameters { get; set; } = new List<Type> { typeof(MyComponent1), typeof(MyComponent2), /* other component types */ };
    
        Dictionary<string, object>? parameters = new() { { "OnInputCallBack", EventCallback.Factory.Create<EventCallbackArgs>(this, GetChangedValue) } };
    
        private bool HasParametersProperty(Type componentType)
        {
            return componentType.GetProperty("Parameters") != null;
        }
    }

Here I have written a service where the actual page provides list of components to be housed in the header part of the MainLayout.
My requirement is I want to access the components rendered in Header bar whenever required and in the event of user changes the values in the header components the page should be able know that.
I was able to implement that using a common event callback in the header components and subscribing it in the actual page but its very messy and I could not the values first time the components in header are rendered.

It sounds like you want to pass info from a parent to a child. If so then use CascadingValue and render the child content inside that tag in your MainLayout: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/cascading-values-and-parameters?view=aspnetcore-8.0#cascadingvalue-component

You'll have to use a RenderFragment object as a parameter to pass in the child content.

If I use cascadingValue How do I get the reference to the dynamic component to passon.

You don't! If you want an alternative to your implementation, you can use a CasacadingValue tag with a rendered fragment. So instead of using the BaseParameters and passing in the types (MyComponent1, MyComponent2, etc...), you create razor views for those types and with some type of control view to handle your values coming into the children. A tab control is a good example: https://blazor-university.com/templating-components-with-renderfragements/creating-a-tabcontrol/

If I read this right, you want to be able to register any component/s you define to be displayed in say the header bar in a Layout.  That component may generate some type of event to tell anyone interested that it's changed.  This sounds like you need an event bus.  Search C# event bus for some examples.  If you scoped isn't that broad, you need to provide some better defined  code showing what you want to achieve or have done so far.

Blazor Sections: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/sections?view=aspnetcore-8.0
